# Can I generate JPA entities with EAGER fetchType by default?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, eager-loading

Im using JPA persistence.xml and generating my entities with the Hibernate code generator. My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="my_schema">
    ... classes ...

    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://10.12.200.101:3306/my_schema"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="my_schema" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="my_user"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="my_pass"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.nombre" value="my_schema" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

All my entities are generated with the FetchType.LAZY by default:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entity_name")
```

Is there a way to generate this entities with FetchType.EAGER by default?

Answer (score 2):

1. All `@ManytoOne` and `@OneToOne` relationships are `EAGER` by default.
2. The `@OneToMany` associations are `LAZY` for a very good reason.
3. Assuming you have a root entity:

   - `Country`, having a one-to-many association states
   - each `State` has a one-to-many association cities
   - each `City` has a one-to-many association streets
   - each `Street` has a one-to-many association `HouseNumbers`

If you have the default option of fetching all these one-to-many associations eagerly, it could be that selection one `Country` will [end up fetching the whole database](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

This is a major performance concern and you should plan your [fetching strategy responsively](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/).

4. If all your one-to-many associations are fetched eagerly, and one parent entity (`Parent`) has 2 unrelated one-to-many associations (children and jobs) then fetching the parent entity will end up in a Cartesian Product of all the one-to-many associations.

So, in conclusion:

- plan your fetch strategy carefully
- rely less on the default `EAGER fetching
- explicitly use fetch joins in all JPQL or Criteria API queries to extract the right amount of info you need for a certain job

Comment: Yes, my problem is with OneToMany relationships indeed. I have a very small database, and then I think the efficiency is not going to be a problem. I don't like the fact that every time I regenerate my entities I have to manually modify all OneToMany relationships.

Comment: But if you have a small database, you don't have that many one-to-many associations. You can simply set the fetch EAGER property for all of them.